# Оператор "is". Один код - разные результаты

Tags: python, python-3.x

Используя оператор **'is'** при одинаковом коде получаю разные результаты:

```
value1 = 257
value2 = 257

print(value1 is value2)
```

Если вводить данный код в **IDLE**, то результат будет **False**.
Если выполнять данный код в **PyCharm**, запустить **файл.py** или **импортировать модуль** результат будет **True**.
Из-за чего мы получаем разное поведение?
Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TL;DR
>   В ряде случаев результат может быть `True`, но рассчитывать на это не стоит.

В интерактивном режиме каждая строчка кода компилируется отдельно, это не позволяет компилятору проводить более глобальные оптимизации кода, отсюда и разница в результатах.

Благодаря оптимизациям компилятора, `value1` и `value2` в некоторых версиях интерпретатора могут ссылаться на одно и тоже значение даже в таком примере

```py
value1 = 128 * 2 + 1
value2 = 257
print(value1 is value2) # True в python 3.7 и False в более ранних версиях
```

Но, например, в таком случае оптимизация не сработает даже в python 3.7

```py
value1 = 257
value2 = value1 + 0
print(value1 is value2) # False
```

И в таком примере переменные также будут указывать на разные объекты

```
value1 = 257
def f():
    value2 = 257
    print(value1 is value2) # False

f()
```

Другое дело, если значения попадают в пул заранее подготовленных объектов, тогда во всех более или менее актуальных версиях CPython оптимизация снова сработает. В данном случае оптимизация времени выполнения

```py
value1 = 256
def f():
    value2 = 512
    value3 = value2 // 2
    print(value1 is value3) # True

f()
```

Но это не часть стандарта языка, а деталь реализации интерпретатора, которая может измениться в следующих версиях, так что на нее не стоит полагаться.

Answer (score 0):

Если в двух словах, то оператор `is` сравнивает не значения переменных, а то, являются ли они одним и тем же объектом в памяти, или же это два разных объекта.

А это может зависеть много от чего. В частности, в ряде случаев интерпретатор может кэшировать какие-то значения (обычно этому подвергаются небольшие целочисленные значения). Но будет использоваться такое кэширование или нет - зависит только от интерпретатора, стандарт языка это никак не ограничивает.

Вообще, `is` обычно нет смысла использовать для чего-то кроме как сравнение с `None`. Или для какой-то особенной магии, когда вам именно нужно знать, что это один и тот же объект в памяти.